# Filtering Push Notifications

Tags: ios, json, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Using Swift 3, I have an app that is a blog reader, it gets the content from a mysql server using json to display the information in a table view. Now my question is this, how can I send the user of the app a notification when new json information has populated the table view? Or has updated existing information? Is there a way to do this?

Also to note, lets say the app has hundreds of users, each user chooses what kind of information they want to be shown. So when the notifications come in, how do I filter them?

Not asking for code, just an idea on what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass additional JSON data in the payload of your APN... You can include something like this in your APN:

```
{"payload": {"message": "This is a test message"}}
```

From there you will need to monitor incoming push notifications in your app using didReceiveRemoteNotification in your appdelegate.swift

From there you can print(userInfo) and see how the data is coming from the notification... You can parse that data using a framework like SwiftyJSON, or you can parse it using custom code.

The rest is up to you.